# Error in gulp.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I tried to run `gulp serve` in my source directory.
This command loaded all files and started to use my *gulpfile.js*.

As result I have the following error:

> ```
> gulpInst.start.apply(gulpInst, toRun);
>               ^
> ```
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
>       at C:\Users...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:129:19
>       at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
>       at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:443:11)
>       at startup (node.js:139:18)
>       at node.js:974:3

First line of *gulpfile.js* is:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
```

It is my first experience with node.js and gulp too. I have got needing to start existing application from sources, and for me this error message looks like error in framework found by framework. I feel that I did something wrong, but do not know what? How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What is `gulpInst` ?

Comment: `var gulpInst = require(env.modulePath);` - from bin\gulp.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to reinstall gulp-cli :

```
npm install -g gulp-cli
```